# call a Javascript function from controller more than once (in Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, file-upload, html, rjs

I have a  multiple file upload form(html5) and want to update my view as soon one of the images is transfered to my image server.

Currently I upload the files with ajax and use [response_to_parent](http://github.com/markcatley/responds_to_parent) to update my upload view when all images are transfered to  the image server.

Is it possible to call a Javascript function from the controller more than once per action?

```
def upload
  params[:images].each do |file|
    upload_to_image_server(file)
    #page << Update upload View
  end
end
```

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is not possible [without extraordinarily hacking into response sockets]. However, there are some alternatives to that.

You can try using [uploadify](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/07/21/uploadify-and-rails23/) (untested), or some comet-like alternative. Another alternative is to use push trough web sockets. [Pusherapp](http://pusherapp.com/docs/quickstart) seems to do the trick (you can call Pusher#trigger several times in a request). Not sure about all-browser compatibility, though.

In general, is better to have quick response controllers, so perhaps tweaking the ajax (or flash) for the image upload to upload one file at a time would be a better approach if you are worried about notifying the user about upload progress.